# How to count number of rows in table while using a where condition in the same query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How to count number of rows in table while using a where condition in the same query.
I am using below query to get the number of rows where departmentname is equal to electrical engineering.But this is now working what is the correct query

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Student
where DepartmentName = 'DepartmentOfElectricalEngineering' ");
cmd1.Connection = conn;
studentdata[4] = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx?ppud=4) has an example that demonstrates the technique.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information. What is the `ExecuteScalar` function returning? Nothing? Is there an exception? what is `studentdata[4]`? ExecuteScalar returns an object, which you need to cast depending on the field (`int` in this case) and the variable where you're storing it. Did you try to run this query against SQL Server directly? Have you tried specifying an explicit field name, like this:

```
Select count(*) as C from Student
where DepartmentName = 'DepartmentOfElectricalEngineering'
```

Comment: execute scalar is returning 1.

Comment: studentdata[4] is an array which is storing the execute scalar value.

Comment: And i want to know what is C in your query and how to get the value which is returned

Comment: 'C' would be just a name you give the field that will contain the result from the `count` operation, although I'm pretty sure it's not needed. I'd try running that exact query in Management Studio and seeing what it returns; it seems correct to me, so the problem might be your data.